# Awk skipping blank lines

Tags: linux, vim, awk

I have this data in a text file. that a need to convert to put in a template

data.txt

```
*   A   11.22.33.44
mail    A   11.22.33.44
domain1.com     A   11.22.33.44
ftp     CNAME   domain1.com
www     CNAME   domain1.com
domain1.com MX mail.domain1.com

*   A   55.66.77.88
mail    A   55.66.77.88
domain2.com     A   55.66.77.88
ftp     CNAME   domain2.com
www     CNAME   domain2.com
domain2.com MX mail.domain2.com
```

Running it though this `vim` command

```
:g/NS/d | :%s/CNAME/cnamerecord/g | :%s/A/arecord/g | :%s/MX/mxrecord/g
```

changes it to:

```
arecord *                11.22.33.44
arecord mail             11.22.33.44
arecord domain1.com      11.22.33.44
ftp     cnamerecord     domain1.com
www     cnamerecord     domain1.com
domain1.com mxrecord mail.domain1.com

arecord *         55.66.77.88
arecord mail             55.66.77.88
arecord domain2.com             55.66.77.88
ftp     cnamerecord     domain2.com
www     cnamerecord     domain2.com
domain2.com mxrecord mail.domain2.com
```

Now I run an AWK command

```
cat data.txt |
awk '{if ($2 == "arecord") print $2 " " $1 " " $3}
     {if ($2 == "cnamerecord") print $2 " " $1 "." $3 " " $3}
     {if ($2 == "mxrecord") print $2 " " $1 " " $3}'
```

and the output is as follows:

```
arecord * 11.22.33.44
arecord mail 11.22.33.44
arecord domain1.com 11.22.33.44
cnamerecord ftp.domain1.com domain1.com
cnamerecord www.domain1.com domain1.com
mxrecord domain1.com mail.domain1.com
arecord * 55.66.77.88
arecord mail 55.66.77.88
arecord domain2.com 55.66.77.88
cnamerecord ftp.domain2.com domain2.com
cnamerecord www.domain2.com domain2.com
mxrecord domain2.com mail.domain2.com
```

Now, there are two problems here:

Problem number 1 and my biggest headache: how do I keep the space between the data. There is a blank line in the file I would like to keep.

Problem # 2 (bonus points): in my AWK code I would like the arecord to show as:

```
arecord *.domain1.com 55.66.77.88
arecord mail.domain1.com 55.66.77.88
arecord domain1 55.66.77.88
```

NOT:

```
arecord * 11.22.33.44
arecord mail 11.22.33.44
arecord domain1.com 11.22.33.44
```

Final ideal output would look like this

```
arecord *.domain1.com 11.22.33.44
arecord mail.domain1.com 11.22.33.44
arecord domain1.com 11.22.33.44
cnamerecord ftp.domain1.com domain1.com
cnamerecord www.domain1.com domain1.com
mxrecord domain1.com mail.domain1.com

arecord *.domain2.com 55.66.77.88
arecord mail.domain2.com 55.66.77.88
arecord domain2.com 55.66.77.88
cnamerecord ftp.domain2.com domain2.com
cnamerecord www.domain2.com domain2.com
mxrecord domain2.com mail.domain2.com
```

I have to do this for 150 domains

Any help would be great

Comment: This is not going to go very far without proper formatting. Can you please format correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you join the separate `if` statements to an `if..else if..else`, you can add a fallback to print all other lines as-is; this will keep the empty lines (as well as any comment lines etc.):

```
cat data.txt | awk '{if ($2 == "arecord") print $2 " " $1 " " $3; else if ($2 == "cnamerecord") print $2 " " $1 "." $3 " " $3; else if ($2 == "mxrecord") print $2 " " $1 " " $3; else print}'
```

Comment: This one is does the job it still is not putting the arecords in right however it is very close to what i need thank you

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that when testing, too; the condition probably needs to be `if ($1 == "arecord") ...`; I think you can figure that out!

Comment: You should not use  `cat` with program that can read data itself, like `awk`:  `awk 'code' data.txt`. And it does not give output as OP requested.  Not adding `domain1.com` to `*` and `mail`

Answer (score 2):

Some like this?

```
cat file
arecord * 11.22.33.44
arecord mail 11.22.33.44
arecord domain1.com 11.22.33.44
ftp cnamerecord domain1.com
www cnamerecord domain1.com
domain1.com mxrecord mail.domain1.com

arecord * 55.66.77.88
arecord mail 55.66.77.88
arecord domain2.com 55.66.77.88
ftp cnamerecord domain2.com
www cnamerecord domain2.com
domain2.com mxrecord mail.domain2.com
```

The awk command

```
awk '
/arecord/ && !c { 
    c=NR+2}
NR==c {
    c=0
    print $1 " *." $2,$3 "\n" $1" mail." $2,$3 "\n" $0}
/^ftp|^www/{
    print $2,$1 "." $3,$3}
/mxrecord/ {
    print $2,$1,$3}
!NF {
    print ""}
' file
arecord *.domain1.com 11.22.33.44
arecord mail.domain1.com 11.22.33.44
arecord domain1.com 11.22.33.44
cnamerecord ftp.domain1.com domain1.com
cnamerecord www.domain1.com domain1.com
mxrecord domain1.com mail.domain1.com

arecord *.domain2.com 55.66.77.88
arecord mail.domain2.com 55.66.77.88
arecord domain2.com 55.66.77.88
cnamerecord ftp.domain2.com domain2.com
cnamerecord www.domain2.com domain2.com
mxrecord domain2.com mail.domain2.com
```

Updated to get rid of `getline`